# Regular expression matching beginning of line OR a set of characters

Tags: regex, go

At first I thought this must be very easy, I am just overlooking something, but so far with my limited knowledge of regex I can't figure this out,

I have a regex like `[some characters]MYNAME` actual thing is:

```
    rx = rx + `[ ,\t,,\,,\(,=,@,\s]+(MYNAME)`
```

I want this regex to **also** detect a line that **starts** with `MYNAME`.
So the question is, is there a way to add `^` inside `[]` with other things? or to `OR` the `^` with a `[some characters]`?

I can't make it work either with javascript or golang. If there are differences related to this matter, I am interested in the golang specific solutions.

Comment: Does the set of characters need to start at the beginning of the line too, or can it be anywhere in a string?

Comment: It can be anywhere so it is either `MYNAME` or `something= MYNAME` should match while, `XMYNAME` should not,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use alternation. Also, there are some unnecessary characters in your character class:

- I don't know what those commas are supposed to do? Did you intent them to act as separator? If yes, remove them.
- Also, you don't need to escape `(` in a character class.
- Since you have added `\s`, you don't need to add `\t` and `" "` separately.

So, your regex can be simplified to:

```
"(?:[(=@\s]+|^)(MYNAME)"
```

Comment: thanks, for all the suggestions, actually I need to keep `\,` in there since I want `,` to match, `(?:[x]|^)` saved me, thanks,

Comment: @Ali If you want to match `,` then just add `,`. No need to escape it.